# Set navigationBar color on Android Lollipop with Full screen activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, navigationbar

Is there a way to set the navigationbar color in a fullscreen activity?

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Theme_color));
```

And this line in my theme-style:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">#E64A19</item>
```

Both resulting in the same transparant navbar above my activities layout...

Code:

Acitivity :

```
@Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //Remove title bar
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                //Remove notification bar
                this.getWindow()
    .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

                if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow()
        .setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Theme_color));
                }


                //other code ... (irrelevant)
```

Theme:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">#E64A19</item>
</style>
```

The result is a black navigationbar. But I want a orange (#E64A19) navigation-bar.

Result:
[image: old result set navbar-color]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution:

The problem lied with the generated code (XML theme) once I'd deleted the `parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar"`attribute from my theme style (and everything else except `<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">#E64A19</item>`) my navbar became orange!

Result:
[image: screenshot with working navbar-color]

Answer (score 0):

Check this library : [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint).

This can be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I want the navbar color only set on lollipop devices because of their material design.
I've managed to get the navbar color working on other activities but just not with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Place this is your values-v21/styles.xml, to enable this on Lollipop

Comment: I have tried that code see first code block in my post.

Comment: Thanks, I've maked some changes to my theme style and everything works. (I've posted my solution)