# navigationbar color not changing

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, navigationbar

I use Lg Q6. Version 7.1.1. Navigation bar color not change with code below. I try to change dynamically and using theme but nothing is change. I dont understand Where Im do something wrong ?

First try programatically

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {                
   getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_awesome_color));
}
```

Then try style.xml

Manifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: Try this: `getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary)`

Comment: Does the color change in any other apps? I'm thinking LG probably blocked this.

Comment: No other app can change at least it can make black navigation bar but I cant

Comment: getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary) doesnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29795777/5192105

Answer (score -1):

Every time you want to change the color of a comment or item in the entire app, it's best to put a special style into it and introduce it to the original style of the program.

For Example : if you want change background of bottom Navigation Bar you can add under lines in style.xml v21 :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

but if you want change background color of toolbar , you should define an style for it , for example :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        .
        .
        .
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyStyle</item>
    </style>

<style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#024dfc</item>
</style>
```

you can use this way for define night and day theme for your app .
I hope you enjoyed .